# How can I create a ranged projection of a SortedSet with no upper-bound

Tags: scala, sortedset

I have a mutable SortedSet of objects, which I would like to split into two halves based on a given median that is not present in the set.  Because the median object isn't in the set, it doesn't have an index to split on.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet

class MyClass(val x:Int)

// order based on a property of the object
val order = Ordering[Int].on[MyClass](mc => mc.x)
val set = SortedSet[MyClass]()(order)

set += new MyClass(3)
set += new MyClass(5)

val median = new MyClass(4)
```

I can use `to` or `until` to get the ranged projection with no lower-bound, but I cannot figure out how to get a ranged projection with no upper-bound.  The method `splitAt` *almost* gives me what I need, but it does not work because it takes an index as a parameter, which I do not have.

```
// this gives me the lower half
set.until(median)
// how do I get the upper half?
```

Is there a good way to get the ranged projection with no upper-bound?  Alternatively, is there a good way to get the correct index to use for the `splitAt` method?  Ideally I would like to find the solution that is the most performant.

Comment: Just a question... Why no case class? :)

Comment: @OniltonMaciel I also made it a case class when trying it out, so you can read the results. Someday SO will suggest edits like this. But by then, the machines will have defeated the humans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [from](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet@from%28from:A%29:This)? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed this.

Comment: The evils of fat interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
val (lower, higher) = set.partition(x => order.lt(x, median))
```

If you don't care about this kind of performance improvement. I usually like this style, seems easier for me too read, more compact, and the performance gains usually are not that important. You could also write it like this (no ordering stuff needed):

```
val (lower, higher) = set.partition(c => c.x < median.x)
```

If you really care about performance you can use the "opposite" of [until](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet@until(until:A):This), [from](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet@from(from:A):This) :

```
set.from(media)
```

Comment: Do you know what the asymptotic complexity of `partition` is?  If this is implemented naively it will be linear, which I would like to avoid.  I do not know if that's the case here, though.

Comment: Probably O(n). Didn't know this kind of optimization was really a problem for you. Linear is usually ok.